# How can i make it so the program adds rows for each new input?

Tags: python, list, vector

I need the program to add rows on its own for every new entry. The user inputs grades and these are stored in different rows and are viewable afterwards.
the input rows should be somthing like:

row=[name, grade 1, grade 2, grade 3, average]

Im new at this and i havent been able to figure it out on my own

Comment: it's unclear what you mean by "add rows on its own for every new entry." Maybe put some expected & actual output in your question, so we'll know how to help you :-)

Comment: Just an observation, I bet you would find more flexibility to save the data in a dictionary, the results would be a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

if

```
row=[name, grade 1, grade 2, grade 3, average]
```

and you are storing different students in a list of lists:

l = [row1, row2 .. row_n]

then you can do:

```
l.append(new_row)
```